# Distances of points around unit circle

Tags: combinatorics

$P_1,\cdots , P_{10}$ are ten points on the unit circle 
What  is the largest possible value of the quantity
$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le 10} |P_i-P_j|^2$$

Comment: It would help if you could indicate from what set the points are (do you mean $\mathbb{R}^n$ or something else?) and what norm you are using. (my guess is euclidean but it could be something else)

Comment: What do you mean $|P_i-P_j|^2$ ?

Comment: @Ridac: if the norm is the Euclidean one, the dimension actually does not really matter.

Comment: Sorry A-M , u r precisely correct , I should have specified sum of squares of distances between pairwise points .

Answer (score 2):

We may just use the identity:
$$\|P_1+P_2+\ldots+P_n\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\|P_k\|^2+2\sum_{1\leq i < j\leq n}\langle P_i,P_j\rangle \tag{1}$$
from which it follows that:
$$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\|P_i-P_j\|^2 = 2(n-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\|P_k\|^2-2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\langle P_i,P_j\rangle\tag{2}$$ can be written as:
$$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\|P_i-P_j\|^2 =\color{red}{-\|P_1+\ldots P_n\|^2}+\color{blue}{(2n-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\|P_k\|^2}.\tag{3} $$
If every $P_k$ lies on the boundary of a unit ball, the blue term is just $\color{blue}{n(2n-1)}$.
The red term is always negative, unless the centroid of $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ is the centre of the previous ball.
Now the question is trivial and, interestingly, dimension-independent.

Comment: could you clarify the third equality?

Comment: @AndresMejia: just put together $(1)$ and $(2)$: it is quite straightforward.

Comment: Ah, I see. It wasn't clear to me that they were together implying the third. Sorry.

Comment: Why are u referring this to a ball ? It's a circle in 2d

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss: as said in the comments and at the end of my answer, terms are chosen in order to underline the dimension-independence of this approach. But anway a 2d-circle is the boundary of a $2$-dimensional unit ball, so I see no issues in my choice of words.

Comment: True so u did the case for N points not 10 right ??

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss: right.

Comment: how ironic the last words of your statement Jack D'Aurizio ! "I see no issues with my words choice " should be " choice of words" !! to be grammatically and phonetically correct :)

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss: appreciate it, now fixed.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\,\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{9}\sum_{j = i + 1}^{10}
\verts{\expo{\ic\theta_{i}} - \expo{\ic\theta_{j}}}^{\color{#f00}{2}} & =
\sum_{i = 1}^{9}\sum_{j = i + 1}^{10}\pars{\expo{\ic\theta_{i}} - \expo{\ic\theta_{j}}}\pars{\expo{-\ic\theta_{i}} - \expo{-\ic\theta_{j}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{i = 1}^{9}\sum_{j = i + 1}^{10}\bracks{2 - 2\cos\pars{\theta_{i} - \theta_{j}}}=
4\sum_{i = 1}^{9}\sum_{j = i + 1}^{10}\,\,\,
\sin^{2}\pars{\theta_{i} - \theta_{j} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & \leq
4\sum_{i = 1}^{9}\pars{10 - i} =
4\pars{9 \times 10 - \half \times 9 \times 10} = \color{#f00}{180}
\end{align}

Comment: "Sum of the squares of distances", not "Sum of the distances".

Comment: Good. And now, note that you are asked for "the largest possible value", not for an upper bound.

Comment: Where did u get the 2(n−1)∑k=1n∥Pk∥2 in second inequality ? Jack D'Aurizio